# How to check foreach loop for a property. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to figure out how to filter my foreach loop and only display an image if my post has one. So far I have been trying different functions and @ifs but to no avail.

Here is my controller code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div>
          <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
          <p>{{$post->body}}</p>
          <img src="{{url('img', $post->image)}}">
        </div>
        <hr>
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `@if`:

```
@if ($post->image)
    <img src="{{ url('img/' . $post->image) }}">
@endif
```

Or `@isset`:

```
@isset ($post->image)
    <img src="{{ url('img/' . $post->image) }}">
@endisset
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#control-structures

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `@if` statement to see if the `image` property of the current `$post` is set. This could look a little something like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div>
        <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
        <p>{{$post->body}}</p>
        @if(!empty($post->image))
            <img src="{{url('img', $post->image)}}">
        @endif
    </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

By including this, the `<img>` element will only be displayed if the property is not empty.

As also mentioned in another answer, you can replace the `@if(!empty(...))` by `@isset(...)` to achieve the same result.